# quotient ring by ideal of zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given a commutative ring $R$ and an element $v$ in $R$, I would like to form a quotient ring in which $v$ does not have any zero divisors.  So I define an ideal $I_v$ to be the set of elements $z$ of $R$ such that $zv=0$, and then I define $R_v = R/I_v$.  Is there a standard name for this construction of $I_v$ and/or $R_v$, so that I might know where to read more about it?  It seems similar to the localization of the ring, but not quite the same.

Comment: These lecture notes discuss the quotient ring to which you are referring http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~tom/old_classes/412notes6.pdf (cf. page 5)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  However I only saw the the general definition of a quotient ring discussed there, not the example I mentioned.  Sorry if I missed it.

Comment: After reading some more, I think the ideal $I_v$ is known as the "annihilator" of $v$, which is defined more generally for a subset of a module over a ring (for me the subset is the single element $v$, and the module is $R$ itself).  But I still haven't seen much discussion of the quotient ring in this case, for example, if it has an interesting properties I might find useful, so any help on this would be appreciated.